# The product of a sequence of certain product of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, infinite-product

Let's say I want to calculate:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\prod_{k=2}^{n}{p_{k}*p_{k}}}{\prod_{k=2}^{n}({p_{k}-2)*p_{k+1}}}$$
where $p_{k}$ is the $k^{th}$ prime.

Basically this is $(3*3)/(1*5) * (5*5)/(3*7) *(7*7)/(5*11) {...}$

Is this infinite product equal to $0$? I am assuming it is because $$\frac{{p_{k}*p_{k}}}{({p_{k}-2)*p_{k+1}}}$$
is mostly less than 1 for large primes, but I cannot find a good proof of why the infinite product should converge to $0$ rather than some other finite number.

Comment: What's $x$ doing there?

Comment: sorry, I meant k

Answer (score 2):

The product

$$\prod_{k=2}^n{\frac{p_k \cdot p_k}{(p_k - 2)\cdot p_{k+1}}}$$

does in fact tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

We can show this by splitting it up into two products as shown below

$$\prod_{k=2}^n{\frac{p_k}{p_{k+1}}} \cdot \prod_{k=2}^n{\frac{p_k}{p_k - 2}}$$

The terms on the left telescope, so we're left with

$$\frac{3}{p_{n+1}} \cdot \prod_{k=2}^n{\frac{p_k}{p_k - 2}} = \frac{3}{p_{n+1}} \cdot \prod_{k=2}^n{\left(1 + \frac{2}{p_k - 2}\right)}$$

As $n$ tends to infinity,

$$\frac{1}{p_{n+1}} \to \frac{1}{n\log(n)}, \ \ \text{  by the PNT, and}$$

$$\prod_{k=2}^n{\left(1 + \frac{2}{p_k - 2}\right)} = O(\log^2(n)).$$

When you multiply the two, their product clearly approaches zero.

Comment: There's a $p_{k+1}$ outside the product over $k$.

Comment: Oh yeah, it’s fixed now